# Using $wpdb to return results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to move from traditional php database config code to the simpler $wpdb since I moved this site to Wordpress. The code below does return the current user fine, but I am doing something (perhaps fundamentally) wrong in using $wpdb to return a count of "movies" from movies for a user. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST ['submit'])){

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

global $wpdb;

}
```

?>

```
Here are your movies: 
<? php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movies.ID = $user_ID' );
$results = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from movies");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

print "<a href=\"http://sitetest.net/active\">" .$data['total'] . "</a><br>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The problem was that if(isset($_POST ['submit'])) code that I had wrapping the rest of the code. Of course, there was no submit form on this page as I had mentioned this was the entire code on the page and that was accidentally copied from another page. From there, John pretty much had it albeit with a tweak or two to the syntax. Thanks all...

```
<?php 
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
?>
Movies Started/Active: <?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(*) as total from movies where ID = $user_ID");
print "<a href=\"http://example.com/active\">" .$results[0]->total ."</a><br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Here are your movies:

```
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(*) as total from movies where `user_ID` = '{$user_Id}'");

print "<a href=\"http://sitetest.net/active\">" .$results[0]->total . "</a><br>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Interesting. Close I think, but I"m getting unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: what line number is the erorr?

Comment: It is saying the line with the $results variable (the select statement line)

Comment: Same result but I don't see anything different in your code form the the first time

Comment: I really think it's a problem with the rest of your code, post a more bigger snippet

Comment: There's nothing else :(

Comment: OK, changed <? php closer to the question mark like <?php to get past T_Variable. Now I get the bigger error I was expecting being a newbie to the $wpdb approach, which is "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object in /home/content/63/8593/html/write/wp-content/plugins/php-code-for-posts/PHPPostCode.php(58)"  so basically it seems we are not using $wpdb global correctly or else it won't work with the plug in that allows php on pages.  that would be odd though since global variables are returned just fine with this plug in such as with $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `movies` WHERE `user_ID`={$user_ID}");
print "<a href=\"http://sitetest.net/active\">{$count}</a><br>";
```

Comment: This looks like an answer but would you care to expand on it?

Comment: same problem as the other answer. Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object in ...plugins/php-code-for-posts/PHPPostCo‌​de.php" Either we are not using $wpdb global correctly or else it won't work with the plug in that allows php on pages. that would be odd though since global variables are returned just fine with this plug in such as with $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

Comment: Of course, my original code in my question works...it just doesn't restrict the records to the user ID and instead lists all records in the table...